# java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)

Tags: java, httpwebrequest, serversocket

```
HttpURLConnection uc = null ;
URLPath = "";
URL url = new URL(URLPath);
uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
uc.setReadTimeout(10000);
uc.connect();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(savePath);
InputStream in = uc.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int Length = 0;
long FinishedLenth = 0;

while((Length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    FinishedLenth = FinishedLenth + Length;
    fos.write(buffer, 0, Length);
}
uc.disconnect();
in.close();
fos.close();
```

This is my function code and if the network is disconnected,
The code will go to exception.
And I write retry function to the exception.
userValue =0,mean retry and 1 is cancel.

```
int userValue = gm.GetIt("Error");
if(userValue == 0){
 gp.interrupt();
 uc.disconnect();
 downloadFile(local,nas,ip,id,pw,fileId,index);
}
else{
 conf.downloadState.get(index).setpercent("fail");
 return false;
}
```

hi, I have trouble.
I write code and the function is download.
And if network is disconnected , user can choose retry or cancel.
But I get the error message.

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out  
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)  
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)  
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)  
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  
    at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(Unknown Source)  
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  
    at Download_File.downloadFile(Download_File.java:54)  
    at downloadFileFunctionThread.run(downloadFileFunctionThread.java:113)
```

And the line 54 is the while(......).

Comment: It means network is still disconnected. Does it every succeed for connected network?

Comment: Yes, if choose retry, and the network connected.It will download again.

Comment: I think maybe go to exception, and choose retry, it call the same download function again,and the error happened. If i download a file, the network is connected, the error doesn't happened.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the [Connectiontimeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout%28int%29) of the `HttpURLConnection` and try to redesign your while loop like:

```
//...
boolean connected = false;
boolean retry = false;

while(!connected & retry) {
    retry = askUserIfHeWantsToRetry();
    connected = uc.connected();
    URL url = new URL(URLPath);
    uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    uc.setReadTimeout(10000);
    uc.connect();
}
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

check your java params

it also can be setted like below

-Dsun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout=12345 -Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=67890